# ajax google map - {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"} with parsererror

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

here's the ajax call

```
var url_map = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lon+"&sensor=false?callback?";
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       dataType : "json",
       url: url_map,
       crossDomain:true,
       success: function(data){
          console.log("success");
       },
       error: function(e){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(e);
       }
)};
```

I tried `jsonp`,`json` as `dataType`. but it still call back the `parsererror` error. also tried to modify the url_map adding `&output=json` or/and removing the `?callback?` parameter.  is there a way to catch a detailed error instead a generic `parsererror`?

what's wrong with my code?

EDIT

in my opinion, it's not a duplicate of the link mentioned. I already have the lat and long. I need to get the country of that coordinates

Comment: Since you want JSONP, the datatype should be `'jsonp'`.  Also, It should be `callback=?` (note the `=`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [json with google geocoding api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681928/json-with-google-geocoding-api)

Comment: I said that I tried both...

Comment: The geocode API simply does not support JSONP.

Comment: I saw that post, @FelixKling, but I don't think it's the same thing I do here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google geocode vai ajax with jsonp, giving an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875445/google-geocode-vai-ajax-with-jsonp-giving-an-error)

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo: It is the same thing you are doing, you may be asking for different data, but it's the same API, and it doesn't support JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the link below and in the comments, googleapis doesn't provide jsonp ajax requests anymore.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638422/trouble-with-jquery-ajax-reading-json) solved my problem.